# Vidalia standalone with new TBB errors out

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vidalia, ssl

```
bash-4.1$ start-vidalia
```

This gives an error:

```
./App/vidalia: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm running TBB on slackware 13.37, and the library does not exist (I've done a search across the whole system). Slackware uses openssl instead.

Comment: I wonder if we should delete this question, now that the bundle it speaks about has been obsolete for years?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `start-vidalia` script in the current version of Tor Browser Bundle, so I don't know what you're running.

Before doing anything else, **obtain a current copy of Tor Browser Bundle**.

The [official instructions](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux) say:

> To run the Tor Browser Bundle, execute the start-tor-browser script:
>
> ```
> ./start-tor-browser
> ```

Trying to start with a different script, even if present, will not work on your older system, as it doesn't have the necessary libraries (which are shipped with TBB instead).

Comment: actually i got it figured out....yes i have a current version of TBB and it is running. but i also wanted vidalia, and there is a vidalia standalone made for this version of TBB (mentioned here in the TBB faq https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowserBundle3FAQ#WheredidtheworldmapVidaliago  ).... as it turns out the vidalia-standalone is missing two libraries, and they need to be copied over from TBB's libraries.... i did get vidalia-standalone working....